# Extreme drop in framerate when playing Dragon Age: Origins for PS3

Tags: ps3, dragon-age-origins

I'm playing Dragon Age: Origins Ultimate Edition for PS3 with the 1.01 patch installed.

Whenever I'm exploring and enter into combat, the game pauses/freezes/the framerate drops to near zero.  After a second or two, it begins to refresh again, but the framerate continues to lag for several seconds after that.  Eventually, after five seconds or so, framerate picks back up to interactive levels.

Is this a known issue?  It makes playing the game a chore, especially when entering areas with lots of mobs.

Comment: Have you noticed slowing with any other games? Any excessive heat dissipation out the back?

Comment: I haven't noticed any issues with framerates for other games; everything else runs without any issues.  The system gets hot, but only as hot as any other PC-like device.  I wouldn't call it excessive.

Comment: System and game versions up to date? If you have any extra fans laying around, try using it to pull the heat away from the back. How old is the PS3? Might be a good idea to open it up and clean any dust build-up out. This could be an indication that your PS3 is becoming worn.

Comment: Yeah, everything's updated.  I looked around to make sure the game is updated to the latest version, but I think it's (understandable) some time since BioWare has released a patch for this game.  The PS3 is a year old.  I haven't noticed excessive dust building, but would probably be worth checking.

Comment: How much hard disk space does your PS3 have?

Comment: At the time I was playing this it was the only thing installed on my PS3.  I have a 250GB version.

Comment: This is not normal. Have you tried any other games on this console?

Comment: Definitely.  All my other games work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If software is ruled out (by updates), the cause most-likely resides in the hardware.

While this doesn't necessarily help your problem, the cause is likely a combination of wear and tear on your PS3 (namely the video processing unit) in culmination with high demands from the game on a potentially older PS3 model.

Not much can be done if the developers ignored older model architecture restrictions besides waiting for a software update to address them.

Try to get your hands on some other games made by the same company and some released around the same time period to see if the problem comes up.